# What is the best way to scan over a list of somethings?

Tags: macros, programming, comma-separated-list

It seems that a common operation needed when defining new commands is to scan over a list of arguments (separated e.g. by a comma, but maybe by something else) and do something with each argument in the list, find the last one, or whatever.

For example to write commands that look like `\Command{a,b,c}` or `\Command{c.d.e}` and
do something with each `a`, `b`, and `c`. See e.g. questions on [defining a list of operators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-can-i-specify-a-long-list-of-math-operators) and [ignoring even numbered inputs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71/need-macro-to-ignore-specific-even-numbered-inputs).

Some solutions have been posted there, but what would be the best idiom to perform such kind of operations? LaTeX's `\@for` looks very nice, but is it possible to use it to scan anything other than comma-separated lists?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have not progressed to the level of processing a list myself but I have been using `etoolbox` by Philipp Lehman for some other TeX programming tasks I am doing. I believe [3.7 List processing](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) should give you a good solution.

For example (on a recent version of `etoolbox`) you can write:

```
\DeclareListParser*{\myfor}{;}
\myfor{\fbox}{item1; item2; item3}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference! It does have some nice commands to process a list of arguments. If you don't mind I can edit your answer to include an example.

Comment: Please go ahead.

Answer (score 11):

I was hoping someone to post a better/nicer solution, but so far this seems to be the best one I've seen.

```
\def\do@scan#1:{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \let\next\relax
  \else
    \DoSomethingWith{#1}\let\next\do@scan
  \fi\next
}
\newcommand{\scanlist}[1]{\do@scan#1:\relax:}
```

Of course instead of `:` one can use `,` or any other sensible separator.

Comment: I agree that this is a very good solution, since it does not require any other package at all and needs very few lines of code nevertheless.

Answer (score 6):

Since Morbusg's answer pushed that question to the top, let me add a LaTeX3 answer. The idea is to convert the list to an internal structure called a sequence, and then map over that sequence `\l_MyMap_seq`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3, xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_MyMap_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMap}{O{,}mm}
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_MyMap_seq {#1} {#2}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_MyMap_seq {#3}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \MyMap{a,b,c}{\fbox{#1} }
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \MyMap[:]{a:b:c}{#1\\}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The first (optional) argument is the delimiter, by default a comma. The second argument is the list, and the third is a function, taking each item of the list as `#1`.

The `xparse` package also provides `\SplitList`, which can be used as

```
\NewDocumentCommand {\foo} { >{\SplitList{.}} m m } { \tl_map_inline:nn {#1}{#2} }
```

hard-coding the delimiter in the definition of `\foo`.

Answer (score 5):

In ConTeXt, [list processing](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Processing_Lists) is done using `\processcommalist`. Suppose you want to apply the macro `\doCommand` over each list element passed to `\Command`. The following definition of `\Command` does this:

```
\def\Command#1{\processcommalist[#1]\doCommand}
```

If the list may contain macros, like

```
\def\Arguments{a,b,c}
\Command{\Arguments,d,e,f}
```

then you can use `\processcommacommand`, like

```
\def\Command#1{\processcommalistcommand[#1]\doCommand}
```

There are a some faster alternatives, `\rawprocesscommalist` and `\rawprocesscommacommand` but they have certain limitations. See the ConTeXt wiki [page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Comma_Separated_Lists) on list processing for details.

To process a list with an arbitrary separator, `\processlist` may be used. `\processlist` takes 5 arguments: beginning of list marker, end of list marker, element separator, command to apply to each element,  and the list. For example, a command `\Command[a:b:c]` that uses colon as the separator, can be defined as

```
\def\Command{\processlist[]:}
```

Comment: but what about lists separated by a character other than a comma?

Comment: `\processlist` can be used to process a list with a particular separator. I added that information in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an LPEG based solution. This is written in ConTeXt, but should be easy to modify for LuaLaTeX

```
\unprotected\def\ProcessListWithDelim#1[#2]#3% delim list command
  {\ctxlua{userdata.ProcessListWithDelim(\!!bs#1\!!es, \!!bs#2\!!es, \!!bs\noexpand#3\!!es)}} 

\startluacode
  userdata = userdata or {}

  function userdata.ProcessListWithDelim(delim, list, command)
    local splitter = lpeg.Ct(lpeg.splitat(lpeg.P(delim)))
    local items    = lpeg.match(splitter, list)

    for i=1,#items do
      tex.sprint(tex.ctxcatcodes, command .. '{' .. items[i] .. '}')
    end
  end
\stopluacode

\def\ShowItem#1{>>>#1<<<\crlf}

\def\CommandA#1{\ProcessListWithDelim,[#1]\ShowItem}

\def\CommandB#1{\ProcessListWithDelim{:}[#1]\ShowItem}

\starttext
\CommandA{A,Comma,Separated,List}


\CommandB{A:Colon:Separated:List}
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a complete example using the `\docsvlist` command provided by [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). The example introduces a package called `csvfont` and its `usecsvfont` environment. The font and formatting of this environment can be set using the package/environment options `font` (which resets the font definition) and `font+` (which appends the font definition). Both options may take a comma-separated list of values; as individual values one may specify the names (without preceding backslash) of LaTeX's font-switching/formatting commands. (This syntax is used in the upcoming version 0.1b of my [`quoting`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package.)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{csvfont.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{csvfont}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox,kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=csf,prefix=csf@}

\newcommand*{\csvfont}{}

\define@key{csf}{font}{%
  \def\csvfont{}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\appto{\csvfont}{\csname ##1\endcsname}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
}
\define@key{csf}{font+}{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\appto{\csvfont}{\csname ##1\endcsname}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\newenvironment{usecsvfont}[1][]{\setkeys{csf}{#1}\csvfont}{}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[font={small,itshape}]{csvfont}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{usecsvfont}
\lipsum[1]
\end{usecsvfont}

\begin{usecsvfont}[font+={bfseries,raggedright}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{usecsvfont}

\begin{usecsvfont}[font={bfseries,raggedright}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{usecsvfont}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...that pushed you over the 50K edge. Glad I could be the one. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution (borrowed form Kevin Walker):

```
% tricky way to iterate macros over a list
\def\semicolon{;}
\def\applytolist#1{
    \expandafter\def\csname multi#1\endcsname##1{
        \def\multiack{##1}\ifx\multiack\semicolon
            \def\next{\relax}
        \else
            \csname #1\endcsname{##1}
            \def\next{\csname multi#1\endcsname}
        \fi
        \next}
    \csname multi#1\endcsname}
```

And some examples of its use:

```
% \def\cA{{\cal A}} for A..Z
\def\calc#1{\expandafter\def\csname c#1\endcsname{{\mathcal #1}}}
\applytolist{calc}QWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM;

% \DeclareMathOperator{\pr}{pr} etc.
\def\declaremathop#1{\expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\csname #1\endcsname{#1}}
\applytolist{declaremathop}{pr}{im}{gl}{ev}{coinv}{tr}{rot}{Eq}{obj}{mor}{ob}{Rep}{Tet}{cat}{Maps}{Diff}{Homeo}{sign}{supp}{Nbd}{res}{rad};
```

Comment: This is very similar to the proposed solutions posted in the original threads (see the question), I wanted to know if there is anything better. Moreover, I would like to process lists of arguments given as `\Command{a,b,c}` or `\Command{a:b:c}`.

Answer (score 2):

Plain example of “Lists in TeX's mouth”, [lambda.sty](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/lambda) ([TUGboat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-2/tb28jeffrey.pdf)):

```
\catcode`@=11
\input lambda.sty
\catcode`@=12
\def\csnameafter#1#2{\expandafter#1\csname#2\endcsname}
\def\MathOp#1{\csnameafter\def{#1}{\mathop{\it #1}}%
  #1} % show it, too
\def\Odd#1{\TeXif{\ifodd#1 }}

\Show\Filter\Odd[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] % => [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]

\Show\Map\MathOp[Rep,Tet,Maps,Diff] $ \Rep\Tet\Maps\Diff $
\bye
```