# How can one undefine an already processed class option?

Tags: packages, document-classes, programming, options

I'm using a class `classX` that accepts class option `optionX`.  Thus, I can write:

```
\documentclass[optionX]{classX} ...
```

Now, as I understand it, being a class option, after `classX` processes this option, `optionX` is globally defined.  All well and good, except that subsequently, for `packageY` that also accepts `optionX` (same option name, however semantically unrelated), the two lines

1. `\usepackage{packageY}`
2. `\usepackage[optionX]{packageY}`

both (erroneously) produce the same effect.  All would be well if I could undefine `optionX` before executing `\usepackage{packageY}.` (At this point I should also note that, lest anyone be worried about how this might affect `classX`'s subsequent performance, there's no need for the slightest concern -- `classX` has no need of this option remaining defined after executing its class `\ProcessOptions`).

So, to the heart of my question, would anyone with better TeX\LaTeX knowledge than I, have any idea how to go?  FYI, I've tried several of the usual suspects: `\let\optionX\@undefined` along with several clueless stabs at `\let\<prefix>@optionX\@undefined` after scouring source2e.pdf.

(JW: sadly I don't think I can hold back for LaTeX3's promised encapsulated namespaces solution. *sigh.*)

Comment: To make it clear: you don't want to muck about with the class or package files themselves, but want to put a command (or something) in between the class being loaded and the package being loaded that "switches off" the option.  Am I right?

Comment: Incidentally, although `classX` has no need of this option, `packageZ` might need to know that `classX` was used with that option.  So even when an answer is forthcoming, use with caution!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant macro seems to be `\@classoptionslist`.  It's a comma separated list of options passed to the class.  So redefining it by stripping out the unwanted options will remove them from the view of later packages.

Test document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft,wibble]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@classoptionslist{a4paper,draft}
\makeatother

\usepackage{options}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Test package:

```
\ProvidesPackage{options}

\DeclareOption{draft}{\message{^^JGot draft^^J}}
\DeclareOption{wibble}{\message{^^JGot wibble^^J}}

\ProcessOptions
```

With reference to a comment I left to the actual question, I would make any redefinitions of `@classoptionslist` a *local* thing (save the real value before modifying it and restore it once the package is loaded) to avoid problems with other packages that might want to know the full list passed to the class.

For how to actually do the modification, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/363/what-is-the-best-way-to-scan-over-a-list-of-somethings) about iterating over a list.

Comment: The kernel includes the slightly-odd macro `\@removeelement` for removing elements from comma-lists. It's rather awkward to use, so I'd go for the `expl3` `\clist_remove_element:Nn` instead if this is an option at all.

Comment: Many thanks Andrew for your energy and knowledge with showing me some light, and you too Joseph for the heads-up about `\@removeelement` and `\clist_remove_element:Nn.` Greatly appreciated both!