# Two different text outputs depending on some parameter definition

Tags: conditionals, class-options

I am using the astronomy and astrophysics class [`aa.cls`](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/readme.html).
I use it with either of the two options: `structabstract` or `referee`.

The first produces 2-column text, the second one-column text.

I have some figures that change appearance when I switch options.

I would like to know if it is possible to do something like this:

```
IF (optional argument equals structabstract) THEN

 {...commands to have the figure of a certain size}

ELSE (if optional argument equals)

 {...commands to have the figure of another size}

END IF
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Related question (no exact duplicate, though): [How do I conditionally execute something based on a documentclass option?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3089/3323)

Comment: The easiest way might be to define the figure width in terms of `\columnwidth`: `\includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{filename}`, for instance.

Answer (score 5):

The `referee` option in your class is set up as

```
\DeclareOption{referee}{\let\if@referee\iftrue}
```

So you can test is with

```
 \makeatletter
  \if@referee TRUE CODE \else FALSE CODE \fi
 \makeatother
```

`structabstract` is set up as

```
 \DeclareOption{structabstract}{\@oldversionfalse}
```

So you could use `\if@oldversion ...\else ...\fi`. The options `oldversion` and `traditabstract` change this switch too. I didn't check the default of the switches.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer an alternate method that I have been using and is adapted from [this answer to setting class options after documentclass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617/4301), which has a few advantages:

- does not rely on the internals of the class, so will work with any document class
- allows you to change the options on the command line via `latex '\def\MyClassOptions{referee}\input{doc}'`

### Code:

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname MyClassOptions\endcsname\relax
  \def\MyClassOptions{draft,twosided}
\fi
\documentclass[MyClassOptions]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
    \IfSubStr{\MyClassOptions}{draft}{%
        DRAFT option was used.%
    }{%
        DRAFT option was not used.%
    }%
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is suited to personal use only. Please don't create a package for users in this way.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: I don't see anything in the question indicating that the question is for creating a package.