# Detect value of option given to documentclass

Tags: standalone, package-options

I would like to be able to detect if the `standalone` package was used with `[preview=false]` or `[preview=true]`.  Not too concerned if this setting was a default or user defined.

Based on [How can one undefine an already processed class option?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/how-can-one-undefine-an-already-processed-class-option), the macro `@classoptionslist` is supposed to be a comma separated list of options passed to the class. I attempted to detect if this macro had the string `preview=true` in it, but this does not yield the correct results.  The following always prints `Package Option: [preview=false]`.

```
\documentclass[preview=true]{standalone}% Does not work
%\documentclass[preview=false]{standalone}% works

\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter%
\newcommand*{\DetectPreviewOption}{%
    \IfSubStr{@classoptionslist}{preview=true}{true}{false}%
}%
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
Package Option: [preview=\DetectPreviewOption].
\end{document}
```

Comment: And the test `\newcommand*{\DetectPreviewOption}{%
         \ifsa@preview\relax true\else false\fi%
}%` isn't the right one?

Comment: @Marco: Yep that is the correct one, seems to work great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\makeatletter%
\newcommand*\DetectPreviewOption{%
  \ifsa@preview true\else false\fi}
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
Package Option: [preview=\DetectPreviewOption].
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Peter: to elaborate: the `preview` option of the standalone class is stored as the if-switch `\ifsa@preview`, so you can simply use this switch.

Comment: It's a bit harder to undo the effect of `preview=true`: the **preview** package would be already loaded.

Comment: @Martin: as already done ,-)

Comment: @Herbert: Yes, I just wanted to state it explicitly. Some beginners might have issues reading it from the source code alone.

Comment: @Martin: using directly the switch implies the `makeatletter...\makeatother` which is annoying ... Creating another name makes sense!

Comment: Sure, With "directly" I meant by using the if-switch (e.g. like you did) and to avoid any `classoptionslist` trickery as original suggested. I just wanted to add some text to your code.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you would be right and `\@classoptionlist` would have this information in (try your example using the `article` class). The behaviour you are seeing is a 'feature' of the `standalone` class, which includes the lines

```
\def\sa@classoptionslist{}
\DeclareDefaultOption{%
  \xdef\sa@classoptionslist{\sa@classoptionslist,\CurrentOption}%
}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*\relax
\let\@classoptionslist\sa@classoptionslist
```

which will remove all of the *known* options from `\@classoptionslist`.

I see that Herbert has proposed a solution: I'm answering here to point out why the approach you've tried is not working in this case.

Comment: `\sa@classoptionslist` loads only undeclared options (`\DeclareDefaultOption`); `\@classoptionslist` is made equal to it so the undeclared options are passed to the packages as usual. The declared options, among which is the boolean `preview`, are dealt with `\ProcessKeyvalOptions` (and are not passed to packages, I guess).

Comment: @egreg: That's what I meant by 'remove the known options', as it copies the unknown ones only 'over' the full list.

Comment: How to print all options used within `\documentclass[]{}`?