# Show ocg layers in handout

Tags: beamer, ocg, handout

Im am using the ocg package to create clickable layers in a pdf presentation. These items are invisible at the start of the presentation. Is there a command or method to show them when I create a handout out of my slides with the `handout` option? I tried the options `printocg=always` and `exportocg=always` but they don't work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A}
\begin{block}{A}
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{ocg}[printocg=always]{ABul01}{Aocg01}{0}\actionsocg{Aocg01}{}{}{A}\end{ocg}
\item \begin{ocg}[exportocg=always]{ABul02}{Aocg02}{0}\actionsocg{Aocg02}{}{}{B}\end{ocg}
\item \begin{ocg}{ABul03}{Aocg03}{1}\actionsocg{Aocg03}{}{}{C}\end{ocg}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here all items should be visible, not only the third one.

Comment: The OCG setting for printing `printocg=...` is only supported by Acrobat Reader, Foxit and the built-in PDF viewers of the Chromium/Chrome browsers. Thus, you get the expected output if you print from within these PDF viewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution that requires a modification of the ocg declarations is to set the visibility variable conditional on whether you are in `handout` mode (see also [Define command depending on whether beamer is in handout mode or not](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54724/define-command-depending-on-whether-beamer-is-in-handout-mode-or-not)). In the example below the visibility is set to 1 if in handout mode, and set to the provided value in normal mode.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{\newcommand\vis[1]{#1}}
\mode<handout>{\newcommand\vis[1]{1}}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A}
\begin{block}{A}
Check for handout mode: \vis{0}   % this line may be deleted
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{ocg}{ABul01}{Aocg01}{\vis{0}}\actionsocg{Aocg01}{}{}{A}\end{ocg}
\item \begin{ocg}{ABul02}{Aocg02}{\vis{0}}\actionsocg{Aocg02}{}{}{B}\end{ocg}
\item \begin{ocg}{ABul03}{Aocg03}{\vis{1}}\actionsocg{Aocg03}{}{}{C}\end{ocg}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result of two runs, one with handout, one without, appearance after opening the file (i.e., without clicking on the items):

[image]

Note that you may need multiple LaTeX runs and a restart of the pdf reader in order to see the changes with or without handout mode. With some trouble you may be able to patch the `ocg` environment to automatically apply the `\vis` command to the third argument.