# Can't set a toggle based on class option value

Tags: macros, etoolbox, class-options, lineno

I'm trying to toggle linenumbers when the class option `man` is passed.
So far I've tried the recommended answer from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27487/detect-value-of-option-given-to-documentclass#27492) but it doesn't work. LaTeX complains with an `Undefined Control Sequence` error.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{manu}

\makeatletter%
\newcommand*\DetectManuscriptOption{%
  \ifsa@man \toggletrue{manu}\else \togglefalse{manu}\fi}
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\DetectManuscriptOption
\iftoggle{manu}{%
  \linenumbers
}

\end{document}
```

The result is that line numbers are not shown.
How can I fix this so that linenumbers are shown when the `man` option is specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\ifsa@preview` from the other answer is an internal command of standalone, not a general hook.

You could do something like this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{manu}


\DeclareOption{man}{\toggletrue{manu}}
\ProcessOptions

\begin{document}

\iftoggle{manu}{%
  \linenumbers
}
blblb
\end{document}
```

But it looks a bit unusual to use `\DeclareOption` and `\ProcessOptions` outside of a package. I'm not completly sure that it has no side effects.

A more standard method would be to check `\@classoptionslist`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{etoolbox,expl3}
\newtoggle{manu}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\clist_set:NV  \l_tmpa_clist{ \@classoptionslist }
\clist_if_in:NnT
 { \l_tmpa_clist } { man }
 { \toggletrue{manu} }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\iftoggle{manu}{%
  \linenumbers
}
blblb
\end{document}
```