# Showing gradetable only when \printanswers is invoked

Tags: exam

Is there a simple way to have a document created with the `exam` class show the grade table only when `\printanswers` is invoked? Wrapping the grade table in a `solution` environment  works but forces me to place it inside a `questions` environment. I've also tried using `\fillin[\gradetable[h][questions]][0em]` (which works for hiding question points), but this triggers the error "Missing number, treated as zero." and a few other errors that mystify me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to hide the grade table, but one way is [shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385579/23418)

```latex
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\usepackage{etoolbox,expl3}
\newtoggle{gradation}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\clist_set:NV  \l_tmpe_clist{ \@classoptionslist }
\clist_if_in:NnT
 { \l_tmpe_clist } { answers }
 { \toggletrue{gradation} }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\iftoggle{gradation}{%
  \printanswers
}
morestufs
\iftoggle{gradation}{%
  \gradetable[h][questions]
}
foobar
\end{document}
```

You may consider the packages `ifthen` or `xparse` also.

You can also take a look at condition compilation with `\ifdef` or `\ifx`