# Create new commands with comma separated arguments

Tags: macros

Whenever a new command is declared, each argument has to be in brackets `{}`, so that a new macro with several mandatory arguments looks like this:

```
\myMacro{1stArg}{2ndArg}{3rdArg}{4thArg}
```

Is there any way to get a macro that looks like this?

```
\myMacro{1stArg, 2ndArg, 3rdArg, 4thArg}
```

Comment: We have a number of (near) duplicate questions on the site. Here are two of the more comprehensively answered ones: [What is the best way to scan over a list of somethings?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/363/2693)  and [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159118/2693)

Comment: You can with   ` xparse`. However, I would not recommend using commas as separators, they're used in too many contexts. Maybe semi-colons?  Do you have something precose in mind?

Comment: Thank you for fast answering. Semicolon is ok, anyway! Thank you: the argument is centered in the answer you addressed.

Comment: There are ways for getting that. Before elaborating extensively, information is needed about how to treat a) spaces surrounding commata and/or arguments b) empty/blank arguments (i.e. consecutive (space separated) commata)  c) arguments that themselves are to contain commata or surrounding spaces--shall there be a possibility of wrapping arguments into braces which get automatically removed while preserving spaces and commata belonging to an argument itself d) Comma(ta) at the end of the argument-list.